# Graylog2 sign in using Google auth

Tags: apache, google-authentication, graylog2

I'm using Graylog 2.2.3 and can't find any clear instruction on how to setup sign through Google Auth.

I've installed the Single-Sign-On plugin indicated here: http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.2/pages/users_and_roles/external_auth.html#single-sign-on
But I can't find how this should be configured to work. Is it something that should be setup through Apache?